# Discord.js: How to ban user that is not in the guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a ban command. I want it to ban like MEE6, Carl, Dyno do. You can either mention a user or specify their account ID. Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = { 
    name: "ban",
    description: "ban someone",
    execute: async(client, message, args) => {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("you don't have enough permissions to use this command.").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
        var guild = message.guild
        let target = message.mentions.members.first() || guild.members.fetch(args[0])

        if(!target) return message.reply("please mention someone to ban.").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));

        if(target.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("you cannot ban a staff member.").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));

        if(target.id === message.author.id) {
            return message.reply("you cannot ban yourself.").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
        }
        if(target.id === client.user.id) {
            return message.reply("you cannot ban the bot.").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
        }

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ')

        if(!reason) reason = "No reason given.";

        let dmembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("You have been banned from Rice Farm #11")
            .addField("Moderator", message.author)
            .addField("Reason", `${reason}`)
            .setDescription(`.`)
            .setColor("RED")
            .setFooter(``)
            .setTimestamp();

        await target.send(dmembed)

        await message.channel.send(`**${message.author.tag}** banned **${target.user.tag}** indefinitely.\nReason: *${reason}*.`)
        await target.ban({reason:reason})

        let reportChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (x) => x.name === 'logs'
   );
        let logchat = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Member Banned")
        .addField("Target", `${target.user} (${target.user.id})`)
        .addField("Moderator", `${message.author} (${message.author.id})`)
        .addField("Reason", `${reason}`)
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setFooter(`ID: ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000000)}`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setThumbnail(target.user.displayAvatarURL());
        await reportChannel.send(logchat)
    }
}
```

And when I try to ban using ID, I get an error: `(node:927) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: target.hasPermission is not a function`

My goal is for the bot to check if a member has permissions only if args[0] is mention.
I understand the error is obvious, but how can I fix that?

Comment: If you understand the error, then think a way around it...

Comment: Also Stackoverflow works by you listing your attempts and what you already tried....   You failed to do this

Comment: @PLASMAchicken where did I say I understand the error?

Comment: > I understand the error is obvious, but how can I fix that?

Comment: if i understand that the error is obvious it doesn't mean i understand how to fix that

Comment: Read the Stackoverflow how to ask. You need to do research on how to fix it, and include what you tried so far, it seems like you just do not want to think about a solution .....

Comment: Did my answer work for you? I am not quite sure what you mean by checking if a member has permissions only if args[0] is mention.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to check for `target.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")` if `args[0]` is an id?

Comment: @AnsonYeung yes

Comment: @eightless I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: @AnsonYeung btw, do you know how to get username from id?

Comment: @eightless
To get the nickname (the one that you can set a different one for different server):  
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname  
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName  
If you want the tag, get the User object then access tag:  
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user  
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag

Comment: @AnsonYeung i meant username, not nickname, and not of member, of id that is args[0]

Comment: Do you mean the discord tag? I've included that in the previous comment too. Also I'm not sure what this return but might be what you want:
`target.user.username` 
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User?scrollTo=username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read correctly, `guild.members.fetch` should return a `Promise` so you should wait for promise to resolve.

```js
let target = message.mentions.members.first() || await client.fetchUser(args[0])
```

However, if it fails, an error will be returned. You should capture the error as below.

```js
let target = message.mentions.members.first()
try {
    target = target || await client.fetchUser(args[0])
} catch (e) {
    return message.reply("User can't be found");
}
```

Edit: to check permission only if args[0] is mention, you can do the following.

```js
let target = message.mentions.members.first()
if (target) {

    // user is using mention
    // we need to check permission

    if(target.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("you cannot ban a staff member.").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
} else {

    // user is not using mention
    // we will try to look for user from discord id

    try {
        target = await client.fetchUser(args[0])
    } catch (e) {

        // discord id is invalid or user didn't put a discord id there.
        // we can't find any user with args[0]

        return message.reply("User can't be found");
    }
}
// here you can do anything with target
```

Comment: thank you for answering, it didn't work before I changed fetchUser to users.fetch (since I am using discord.js v13). Anyway, your answer helped!

Answer (score 1):

You probably using an up-to-date version of `discord.js` but legacy code. I just looked up and down in the docs for discord.js looking for `hasPermission` method you are using. I only found it in version v11 & v12, however it doesn't seem included from >= v13 and up.

**V12**
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission

**V13**
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.0.1/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions

So your best bet is looking at the property `permissions` . Also maybe check which version you are using.

Comment: I am using v12, but my goal is for the bot to check if a member has permissions only if args[0] is mention.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question as the op said ban using ID is the origin of error.

Comment: @eightless you should in include this extra info in the OP !

Comment: @AnsonYeung I focused on the error ... which IMHO is not irrelevant from the question.

Comment: @PascalLamers `message.member.hasPermission` in the previous lines works but `target.hasPermission` don't so I know he is using a version with `hasPermission` supported. Sorry for being rude to you.

Comment: @AnsonYeung You weren't rude , don't worry :P It wasn't clear to me that the previous lines worked for him - so knowing the version definitely helps in that case. <3